# Ruby recieving text between words

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a problem regarding filtering text between 2 words,
the string that I'm trying to filter looks like this:

```
Word 1
   this is text
   more "text"
   this is more text
 end
 Word 3
   this is more text
   more "text"
   this is more more text
 end
```

What I am trying to do is filtering the pieces of the text between "Word" and "End" and put them seperatly in an 2d array like so

```
array = [["this is more text /n more "text" /n this is more text"]["this is more text /n more "text" /n this is more more text"]
```

What I have now atm is this:

```
test = []
result = string.san(/Word\s.(.*?)end/m)
res.each do |r|
   test.push(r[0])
end
return test
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Kind regards

Comment: Please check both, your spelling and your code before posting something.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.scan(/(?<=Word\s\d).*?(?=end)/m).map &:strip
#⇒ [
#  [0] "this is text\n   more \"text\"\n   this is more text",
#  [1] "this is more text\n   more \"text\"\n   this is more more text"
#]
```

Comment: I will try this :) looks promising

Answer (score 0):

How is your string defined? Is it in a file?

If it's in a file.

```
string = File.read('my_file.txt')
string.scan(/Word\s.(.*?)end/m)
#=> [["\n   this is text\n   more \"text\"\n   this is more text\n "], ["\n   this is more text\n   more \"text\"\n   this is more more text\n "]]
```

Otherwise ignore the first line.

Comment: It is not in a file . It gets passed to this method as a string :)