# Ruby regex to get text blocks including delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

When using scan in Ruby, we are searching for a block within a text file.

Sample file:

```
sometextbefore
begin
  sometext
end
sometextafter
begin
  sometext2
end
sometextafter2
```

We want the following result in an array:

```
["begin\nsometext\nend","begin\nsometext2\nend"]
```

With this scan method:

```
textfile.scan(/begin\s.(.*?)end/m)
```

we get:

```
["sometext","sometext2"]
```

We want the begin and end still in the output, not cut off.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just wrap the whole expression in another matching group. And remove the inner group, because you're not interested in it.

Comment: Something like this: `/(begin\s..*?end)/`

Comment: There have been a few questions like this recently. Is this from an online course / tutorial?

Comment: Just use a non-capturing group, see http://ideone.com/eisqDl. @Stefan: if there is an identical question, please share a link.

Comment: Still looking for it, this is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705131/ruby-recieving-text-between-words

Comment: Well, that is a bit different, and all answers have 0 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You may remove the capturing group completely:

```
textfile.scan(/begin\s.*?end/m)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/eisqDl)

The `String#scan` method returns captured values only if you have capturing groups defined inside the pattern, thus a non-capturing one should fix the issue.

**UPDATE**

If the lines inside the blocks must be trimmed from leading/trailing whitespace, you can just use a `gsub` against each matched block of text to remove all the *horizontal* whitespace (with the help of `\p{Zs}` Unicode category/property class):

```
.scan(/begin\s.*?end/m).map { |s| s.gsub(/^\p{Zs}+|\p{Zs}+$/, "") }
```

Here, each match is passed to a block where `/^\p{Zs}+|\p{Zs}+$/` matches either the start of a line with 1+ horizontal whitespace(s) (see `^\p{Zs}+`), or 1+ horizontal whitespace(s) at the end of the line (see `\p{Zs}+$`).

See another [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/tCmpn0)

Comment: Is a capturing group needed at all? `/begin\s.*?end/m` seems to work.

Comment: Perhaps tack on `.map { |s| s.delete(' ') }` to conform with the OP's specification.

Comment: A bit of tweaking is needed. `str = "begin\n   cat\nend\nTime to begin\nto ensure\n a happy ending"; str.scan(/begin\s.*?end/m)
 #=> ["begin\n   cat\nend", "begin\nto ensure\n a happy end"]`. Maybe `str.scan(/^begin\s*\n.*?^end\s*$/m).map { |s| s.delete(' ') }
 #=> ["begin\ncat\nend"]`.

Comment: Sorry to hear it's your last day. I've enjoyed reading your answers. Was going to a spa your final wish?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, using Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/). I cannot say I would recommend this approach, but Rubiests should understand how the flip-flop operator works.

First let's create a file.

```
str =<<_
some
text
at beginning
begin
  some
  text
  1
end
some text
between
begin
  some
  text
  2
end
some text at end
_
  #=> "some\ntext\nat beginning\nbegin\n  some\n  text\n  1\nend\n...at end\n" 

FName = "text"
File.write(FName, str)
```

Now read the file line-by-line into the array `lines`:

```
lines = File.readlines(FName)
  #=> ["some\n", "text\n", "at beginning\n", "begin\n", "  some\n", "  text\n",
  #    "  1\n", "end\n", "some text\n", "between\n", "begin\n", "  some\n",
  #    "  text\n", "  2\n", "end\n", "some text at end\n"]
```

We can obtain the desired result as follows.

```
lines.chunk { |line| true if line =~ /^begin\s*$/ .. line =~ /^end\s*$/ }.
      map { |_,arr| arr.map(&:strip).join("\n") }
  #=> ["begin\nsome\ntext\n1\nend", "begin\nsome\ntext\n2\nend"]
```

The two steps are as follows.

First, select and group the lines of interest, using [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) with the flip-flop operator.

```
a = lines.chunk { |line| true if line =~ /^begin\s*$/ .. line =~ /^end\s*$/ }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ff62b981510>:each>
```

We can see the objects that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
a.to_a
  #=> [[true, ["begin\n", "  some\n", "  text\n", "  1\n", "end\n"]],
  #    [true, ["begin\n", "  some\n", "  text\n", "  2\n", "end\n"]]]
```

Note that the flip-flop operator is distinguished from a range definition by making it part of a logical expression. For that reason we cannot write

```
lines.chunk { |line| line =~ /^begin\s*$/ .. line =~ /^end\s*$/ }.to_a
  #=> ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

The second step is the following:

```
b = a.map { |_,arr| arr.map(&:strip).join("\n") }
  #=> ["begin\nsome\ntext\n1\nend", "begin\nsome\ntext\n2\nend"]
```

Comment: Ok, so, you decided to split blocks into lines, trim from whitespace and join. I will provide a regex solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has some great methods in Enumerable. `slice_before` and `slice_after` can help with this sort of problem:

```
string = <<EOT
sometextbefore
begin
  sometext
end
sometextafter
begin
  sometext2
end
sometextafter2
EOT

ary = string.split                  # => ["sometextbefore", "begin", "sometext", "end", "sometextafter", "begin", "sometext2", "end", "sometextafter2"]
            .slice_after(/^end/)    # => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fb1e20b42a8>:each>
            .map{ |a| a.shift; a }  # => [["begin", "sometext", "end"], ["begin", "sometext2", "end"], []]
ary.pop # => []
ary # => [["begin", "sometext", "end"], ["begin", "sometext2", "end"]]
```

If you want the resulting sub-arrays joined then that's an easy step:

```
ary.map{ |a| a.join("\n") } # => ["begin\nsometext\nend", "begin\nsometext2\nend"]
```